# Zelle and Graphics.py - how can I keep the graphic window always on top?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

Using graphics.py, I am wondering if there is a way to keep the graphics.py canvas/window on top the entire time.  When using pycharm, if the input is in pycharm - the graphic gets hidden behind the application.  I found a way of doing it in turtle, but cannot seem to incorporate that into graphic.py

Here is the turtle:

```
rootwindow=turtle.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
rootwindow.call('wm','attributes','.','-topmost','1')
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this in Zelle's?

Here is a simple example, when going to the console in pycharm, the graphic window moves behind pycharm instead of remaining on top

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("MyWindow", 200, 200)

def cir(radius):
    cir = Circle(Point(30,30), radius)
    cir.setFill("red")
    cir.draw(win)
    return

radius=int(input("what size of circle?"))
cir(radius)
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it basically the same way as with the `turtle` module, the slightly tricky/hacky part is determining what the root window is. There's at least a couple of ways to do that, but I thought using the universal widget method [`nametowidget()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) was the cleanest (note: `'.'` is always the root's [window name](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/window-names.html) in `tkinter`).

```
from graphics import *


win = GraphWin("MyWindow", 200, 200)
rootwindow = win.nametowidget('.')
rootwindow.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')

def cir(radius):
    cir = Circle(Point(30,30), radius)
    cir.setFill("red")
    cir.draw(win)
    return

radius = int(input("what size of circle?"))
cir(radius)
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

**Recommendation**

In my opinion it would be better for you to learn how to use the `graphics` module's `Entry` object to get keyboard data from the user because that way you wouldn't need to do something hacky like this.